# Is it possible to use only Amplify Auth in a react app in isolation?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I am bit new in this. I have a web app based on react and we have been using authentication using AWS cognito. I was using `amazon-cognito-identity-js` to signup users in the userpool and for login.

Now i am trying to replace that library with `aws amplify auth` because of its clean interface. But i dont want to go through the setup process (amplify init and everything), i want to use it like i used `amazon-cognito-identity-js`.

This is what i have done so far,

I have configured the `Amplify Auth` in my `app.js` file -

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {

        // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'my id pool',

        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'my-region',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'my-userpool',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: 'my app client',

        // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
        mandatorySignIn: true,

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
    }
});
```

Here is what i have done to signup in my `Registration` component -

```
const { username, password, email, name } = this.state;
    try {
        const result = await Auth.signUp({
            username,
            password,
            attributes: {
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                'phone_number': '',
            },
        });

        this.setState({showVerificationCode: true});
    } catch(e) {

        console.log(e);
    }
```

Now when i try to signup an user in my user pool, the user is created and the verification mail has been sent as well. But on the client side i am getting this error -

[image]
Can anyone please tell me if it is possible what i am trying? Do you think i can use only the `Auth` of `aws amplify` in isolation in the client side without any cloud or anything to just user signup and login in user pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That is an issue for this.](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3484)

You figured it out correctly, AWS Amplify is adding Analytics. But instead of configuring it with disabled Analytics like you did, the suggested fix is to use [modular imports:](https://hackernoon.com/modular-imports-with-aws-amplify-daeb387b6985)

```
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
```

If you do

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
```

it automatically loads `Auth`, which causes the error.

Comment: Note that you don't need to import ''Amplify', you can simply import 'Auth' and then use 'Auth.configure({...})'

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i have figured out why the error was occurring. I am writing down as answer so that people who stumble upon this can get an answer -

It seems like `aws amplify` use the `Analytic` service by default and try to log the 'auth' events. So i needed to disable it in the config -

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {

        // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'my id pool',

        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'my-region',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'my-userpool',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: 'my app client',

        // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
        mandatorySignIn: true,

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
    },

    Analytics: {
        disabled: true,
    }
});
```